# Google App engine Flex Env 502 Bad Gateway from nginx - Blazor (.Net 6.0 Target F/W)

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

i am a GCP novice. Just trying to deploy a Blazor Application to GCP App engine using App.Yaml with runtime: custom and Dockerfile to specify the image for this env.
I have attached both files here.
The app gets published but when i try to browse i get a 502.
In the logs explorer for GAE Apps by selecting nginx errors I get the following error with the text payload of

```
 \[error\] 34#34: \*156 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 142.250.182.52, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/", host: "main-composite-383305.el.r.appspot.com"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

ADD ./ /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://\*:${PORT}

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT \[ "dotnet", "MyApp.dll" \]
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
```

I tried - 1. Using Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio - This actually says "Deployment Failed"
2. Using the App Engine Flex Deployment of a published app. I publish to local folder and then use gcloud command line to deploy using gcloud app deploy <app.yaml>